# PugJS form POST with empty body data {} when submitting

Tags: html, forms, post, pug

I have a Pug file with a simple login form:

```
form(name='signup' action='/auth/signup' method='post')
.form-floating.mb-3
    input#emailInput.form-control(type='email' placeholder='name@example.com')
    label(for='emailInput') Email address 
.form-floating.mb-3
    input#passwordInput.form-control(type='password' placeholder='Password')
    label(for='passowordInput') Password
input#btnSignin.btn.btn-secondary(type='submit' value='Sign In')
```

And this is my router file:

```
const express = require('express');

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.route('/signup').post((req,res)=>{
    res.json(req.body);
});

module.exports = authRouter;
```

In app.js I have these two set up as well:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
```

However, when I submit the form, I get empty brackets {} as if there wasn't anything in the inputs. I really appreciate any assistance, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I forgot to set a name in the inputs. It's now working:

```
form(name='signup' action='/auth/signup' method='post')
.form-floating.mb-3
    input.form-control(name='email' type='email' placeholder='name@example.com')
    label(for='emailInput') Email address 
.form-floating.mb-3
    input.form-control(name='password' type='password' placeholder='Password')
    label(for='passowordInput') Password
input#btnSignin.btn.btn-secondary(type='submit' value='Sign In')
```